# Detect whether generator's __iter__ is called with list()

Tags: python, generator

Is there any way to detect whether a generator's `__iter__` is called with list()? As I understand it, list(obj) will call `__iter__`; however, in the case of an infinite generator, I want it to return an error.

For example, I have the following generator:

```
def gen():
    while 1:
        yield 1
```

Since calling list(gen) will result in an infinite loop, I want to make it so that it returns an error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is not the responsibility of `__iter__` to ensure this, and I don't feel it is the responsibility of `list()` either.  It is the responsibility of you, the programmer!

Comment: Who are you trying to protect with this? If you name your infinite generators appropriately, it should be clear to whoever writes the call to the generator what's going on; e.g. if you write `list( allPrimeNumbers() )` you deserve what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no sensible way to do this**. You might be able to hijack the stacktrace, but it'll be ugly and error-prone.

(Obviously, what you're trying to do is not how an iterable is expected to behave in Python, which is another good reason not to do it.)

Besides, it won't loop forever, but keep trying to allocate memory for the list. As soon as this fails, a `MemoryError` will be thrown and the interpreter may or may not recover.

Comment: Thanks. I might hack together a custom type with separate `next` and `__iter__` attributes.

Comment: Did you not basically expand on what I said?

Answer (score 2):

Not without horrible black magic that I will not go into here. Just write in the docstring, "This is non exhaustive." And try to remember not to call list on it.

Answer (score 0):

While it wasn't what I asked for, here is a solution which does basically the same thing:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.generate = self.gen()
        self.next = self.generate.next
    def gen(self):
        for a in range(10):
            yield a
    def __iter__(self):
        raise ValueError
```

```
>>> a = test()
>>> a.next()
0
>>> list(a)
ValueError:
```